# Cannot get lines of small length to show up in plot

Tags: r

I am having problems getting segments of small lengths to appear in my plot.

Assuming the following sample data:

```
x=c(11,22,33,44,55)
y=c(15,23,33,45,57)
z=strptime(20120101:20120105,'%Y%m%d')
```

If I were to create segments out of this data my segment for the third record does not show up if I want square or butt line ends.  It does show up if I allow my line ends to be round `lend=0`.

```
plot(z,x,type='n')
segments(as.numeric(z),x,as.numeric(z),y,lwd=5,lend=2)
```

If I try this:

```
segments(as.numeric(z),x,as.numeric(z),y,lwd=5,lend=0)
```

It shows a circle at 33.  Is there a way to get at the very least a flat line that will appear at 33 (hopefully in base)?

I would have used my actual data which is also doing this when the range is small for instance 33.0005 to 33.0010, but that data is huge and I was hoping solving for when they are identical would also solve for small ranges.

ETA: If `lwd=15` the circle looks even more ridiculous.

Maybe segments are not the right way to approach this?

This is for a candlestick chart, so these numbers would represent open and close.  I also have high and low numbers which extend beyond this range and are drawn using `lwd=1` under these segments.

Comment: (1) If you ask R to draw a segment of length 0, why would R draw anything? (2) In your real example, surely it's possible that on the scale of your plot, a distance of 0.0005 could be below your screen's resolution?

Comment: I agree, but why does it draw something when the `lend=0`?

Comment: Possibly because in order to create that style of line ending, R is actually plotting a filled circle at an "endpoint"? (I'm honestly not sure.)

Comment: I guess using segments then, is the wrong approach.  Even though record 3 in the above example ranges from 33 to 33, there actually is an occurrence at 33 and that needs to show up on the plot.  Maybe there is a different way to do this like boxplots like Carl mentions below.  I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base graphics does supply rect.  And in fact, it does what you want.  Using your definitions above.

```
xdiff <- max(as.numeric(z)) - min(as.numeric(z))
segwidth <- xdiff/50

plot(z,x,type='n')
rect(z-segwidth/2, x, z+segwidth/2, y, col="black")
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Joran points out, this may well be the "correct" behaviour.

But a kludgy workaround is to simply add an arbitrary small number to the values. This value should be small enough to not "distort" the data, but large enough to show up in your plot, given your plot device resolution.

```
delta <- pmax(0.2, y - x)

plot(z,x,type='n')
segments(as.numeric(z),x ,y1 = y + delta, lwd=10, lend=1)
```

[image]

---

PS. I advise against this.  You have been warned.

Comment: +1 for advising against it.  As I always ask: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  That is: what exactly do you want to show in your graph?  Is there some underlying relationship between your X and Y data that you're looking for?  Is it more interesting or less interesting when X==Y ?   Answer those and you can figure out what the graph should emphasize.

Comment: I also have an issue with tampering with the data.  This portion would represent the open and close part of a candlestick chart.  So if I put nothing there, one will not have the open/close quote information for that day.  I also have different sets of data with different ranges so this solution would also require changing the `pmax` value for each set of data, although that should not be too much of a problem.  I was hoping there would be a clean way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you will get the desired result using `boxplot` ?

Comment: Carl, I am going to give this a try.

Comment: @thequerist Why don't you just plot a symbol at the start and end point of each line?

Answer (score 2):

Given the edits to your question, I suspect the way to go about this is to plot points to indicate your open and close, and a segment to indicate the range.

In this way, if your open and close points are identical (or close), you get a symbol at the correct point.

```
x <- strptime(20120101:20120105,'%Y%m%d')
y1 <- c(11,22,33,44,55)
y2 <- c(15,23,33,45,57)

r <- range(c(y1, y2)) 

plot(c(x, x), c(y1, y2), type="n", xlab="Date", ylab="y")
points(x, y1, pch=18)
points(x, y2, pch=18)
segments(as.numeric(x), y0=y1, y1=y2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's something a little odd about "square" lineend

```
library(grid)
epsilon <- 1e-4
grid.newpage()
grid.points(x=c(0.5-epsilon,0.5+epsilon), y=c(0.5,0.5), pch="+", gp=gpar(cex=2), def="npc")
grid.segments(0.5-epsilon, 0.5, 0.5+epsilon, 0.5, gp=gpar(lineend="square",lwd=50, alpha=0.2))
grid.segments(0.5-epsilon, 0.5, 0.5+epsilon, 0.5, gp=gpar(lineend="round",lwd=50, alpha=0.2))
grid.segments(0.5-epsilon, 0.5, 0.5+epsilon, 0.5, gp=gpar(lineend="butt",lwd=50, alpha=0.2))
```

the behavior has a jump at epsilon = 0,

[image] for epsilon=1e-4 vs

[image] for epsilon=0

As a workaround, I would draw rectangles instead of lines; they always have at least one linewidth.

```
grid.newpage()
grid.rect(x=0.5, y=0.5, width=0.01, height=0, gp=gpar(fill="black", col="red", lwd=10, linejoin="mitre"))
```