# change plotted segment ends from round to flat

Tags: r

When i use `segments()` to draw a segment using R, the ends always appear rounded. How can I change the ends to flat?

Comment: please, have a look at whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: A good first step would be to read the documentation for `?segments`, and keep in mind that when R talks about "graphical parameters" it means "things that change the appearance of what you're plotting". If you do that you'll find the answer very easily.

Comment: Pssst... type `?par` for a large list of the 'graphical parameters' you can change.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From `?par`:

```
 ‘lend’ The line end style.  This can be specified as an integer or
      string:

      ‘0’ and ‘"round"’ mean rounded line caps [_default_];

      ‘1’ and ‘"butt"’ mean butt line caps;

      ‘2’ and ‘"square"’ mean square line caps.
```

For example:

```
plot(0:1,0:1,type="n")
par(lend=0); segments(0,0.2,1,0.2,lwd=8)
par(lend=1); segments(0,0.4,1,0.4,lwd=8)
par(lend=2); segments(0,0.6,1,0.6,lwd=8)
```

or `segments(0,0.2,1,0.2,lwd=8, lend=1)` etc.
[image]

(You have to look pretty carefully to see the difference, especially between "butt" and "square" caps)

Comment: [with thick transparent lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869679/471093) you can highlight the difference more easily (try epsilon=0.1)

Comment: it should be possible to pass graphical parameters such as `lend` straight to `segments()`, without the extra `par()` call

Comment: I'm always uncertain about which plotting functions pass which parameters through.  I don't remember exactly, but I seem to remember it's not 100% consistent.